# Have more than 256GB in nsf application

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, hcl-notes

I have a nsf app that has maxed out at 256GB. I've already compacted and it's still too big.

I have tried with "test nsf" to archive the old documents, but the lotusscript encoding and formulas are not prepared for many situations (such as modifying an archived document, gives error "Cannot execute the specified command" in case of @Command([EditDocument])).

My English is very bad, so I leave a drawing with the idea:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPl1a.png)

I want the user to be able to see all the documents, and be able to edit the old ones if they get the error "Database (.nsf) has grown too large".

Comment: This is way to big question for this platform: You need someone with development skills to develop this feature for you as all formulas and LotusScript code need to be adjusted for this to work. 

There is no easy "click here" or "use this command" to solve your problem. 
I am afraid you need to hire a specialist to do this for you. 

As written your question is way to broad...

Comment: If your database is on the server only and there are a lot of attachments in it, you can try to enable DAOS on the server and database. DAOS stores the attachments separate from the database, so the actual database becomes smaller. It does not work on local replicas. (see help for more info)

Comment: @TomVanAken Thank you. I will try activating DAOS.
The second option I think may be to archive the documents that do not have much chance of being edited.
Another possible option is to modify code and formulas so that it retrieves the archived documents when they execute an edit event.